# can't unmarshal string into Go value of type struct

Tags: javascript, ajax, go

I run below javascript code.

```
return $.ajax({
                    url: "/loyalty/api/rule/new",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({'rule':$('form').serializeObject(),'ruleId':ruleID(),'programId':parseInt(proID)})
 });
```

and I use below code to decode it.

```
decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var rules models.NewRule
    err := decoder.Decode(&rules)
```

but then it gives below error message.

```
level=error msg="json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type models.NewRule" api="/rule/new" code=400 tenantid=7 username=admin
```

can you help me to fix this?

my NewRule struct

```
type NewRule struct {
    TenantID  int                `db:"tenantId"json:"tenantId"`
    ProgramID commons.NullInt64  `db:"programId"json:"programId"`
    RuleID    commons.NullInt64  `db:"ruleId"json:"ruleId"`
    Rule      commons.NullString `db:"rule"json:"rule"`
}

func (p NewRule) String() string {
    b, _ := json.Marshal(p)
    return string(b)
}
```

Comment: Show the JSON text. The error message is telling you that a JSON string cannot be decoded to a NewRule.

Comment: I think you should post the JSON that is causing the error, but it seems to me that the error message states exactly what the problem is, you have a JSON string, and you need a JSON object (with keys and values) in order to decode into a struct.

Comment: Add to your script `console.log(r.Body)` and `console.log(JSON.stringify(r.Body))` and post the result of the logging to console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding how `serializeObject` works in JavaScript. From the [fine manual](https://github.com/macek/jquery-serialize-object#api):

> **.serializeObject** — serializes the selected form into a JavaScript object
>
> ```
> $('form#contact').serializeObject();
> //=> {user: {email: "jsmith@example.com", pets: ["cat", "dog"]}}
> ```
>
> **.serializeJSON** — serializes the selected form into JSON
>
> ```
> $('form#contact').serializeJSON();
> //=> '{"user":{"email":"jsmith@example.com","pets":["cat","dog"]}}'
> ```

`serializeObject` gives you an *object* so this:

```
{'rule': $('form').serializeObject(), 'ruleId': ruleID(), 'programId': parseInt(proID)}
```

will give you something like this JavaScript:

```
{
    rule: { /* some JavaScript object goes here */ },
    ruleId: 6,
    programId: 11
}
```

So the `"rule"` key in the JSON will have a whole object (not a string) as its value and `decoder.Decode` correctly refuses to unpack an object into a string.

If you want the `rule` to be a string of JSON encoded data when you unpack it then you want JSON inside your JSON:

```
data: JSON.stringify({
    'rule': $('form').serializeJSON(), // <---- serialize the form to JSON, not an object
    'ruleId': ruleID(),
    'programId': parseInt(proID)
})
```

Then what you're doing should work and you'll end up with JSON encoded data in `rules.Rule` in Go.